# How to match a regular expression on a slow/hanging io.Reader in Go?

Tags: go

I'm working on an application that needs to be able to identify a bunch of different protocols in the middle of an existing `net.Conn`. I have a database containing patterns for all of these in the form of regular expressions. The problem is, I need to be able to take action as soon as I find a match. (trying to get multiple regex matchers running in parallel is out-of-scope for this question)

[Here](https://go.dev/play/p/y7-Po9PqxSE) is a simplified example. I have a custom `RuneReader` (standing in for my `net.Conn`) that will print each rune as it is read.

```golang
type RuneReader struct {
    S   string
    ptr int
}

func (r *RuneReader) ReadRune() (rune, int, error) {
    if r.ptr >= len(r.S) {
        return 0, 0, io.EOF
    }
    ru := r.S[r.ptr]
    fmt.Printf("Read char at position %d: %c\n", r.ptr, ru)
    r.ptr++
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    return rune(ru), 1, nil
}

func main() {
    rr := &RuneReader{S: "HelloWorldItsMeBilly"}
    matched, err := regexp.MatchReader("World", rr)
    fmt.Printf("Match result: %t %v\n", matched, err)
}
```

```
Read char at position 0: H
Read char at position 1: e
Read char at position 2: l
Read char at position 3: l
Read char at position 4: o
Read char at position 5: W
Read char at position 6: o
Read char at position 7: r
Read char at position 8: l
Read char at position 9: d
Read char at position 10: I
Read char at position 11: t
Match result: true <nil>
```

The trouble is, in this example `MatchReader` doesn't stop at "World" like you might expect; It goes on to read 2 more characters. In this example, that isn't such a big deal. It means the match is slower to return. In real-life examples though, a client might be waiting on me to continue. They might expect me to take the next "turn" in the protocol. In order to do that, I need to know that one of the patterns matched (and specifically which one, but for now we are simplifying to the case of a single pattern).

It turns out this behavior is [documented](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp) ([and I'm not the first one tripped up by it](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21883)):

> There is also a subset of
> the methods that can be applied to text read from a RuneReader:
>
> MatchReader, FindReaderIndex, FindReaderSubmatchIndex
>
> This set may grow. Note that regular expression matches may need to
> examine text beyond the text returned by a match, so **the methods that
> match text from a RuneReader may read arbitrarily far into the input
> before returning.**

ok, cool. I understand that some regular expressions may need to examine characters beyond the match, but some clearly don't, and it looks like the standard library's implementation insists on examining characters it doesn't need to. How many? Maybe 2? Maybe more sometimes?

One way to deal with this would be to feed it an EOF whenever I wanted it to look for matches. The problem is that I have no way to "checkpoint" the internal regex state machine, so if I want to continue matching later I have to start over. This is equivalent to re-trying the pattern on the entire connection history after every call to `Read()`. With lots of packets, I would wind up re-scanning the beginning the stream over and over. I can mitigate this by watching timing, so I only re-scan things when the client is quiet for a bit, but I really want a cleaner solution and I know that it is at least theoretically possible.

Is there any way I can use the standard library (or any other pure-go regex library) to match against a stream of data with more predictable match characteristics?

Comment: Since you want to identify protocols, presumably you can put some upper bound on the length of the longest possible match of all patterns, right? Say, 1kB, probably less? In that case you don't have to "re-try the pattern on the entire connection history". Keeping the latest 2*N bytes around is sufficient and reasonable (where N is the upper bound): https://go.dev/play/p/idPLbvpgXwM

Comment: ... this also makes it trivial to match multiple patterns. I don't see how you'd do it with RuneScanners without copying data like crazy. Keeping track of the offset into the buffer for each pattern is necessary to avoid matching the same bytes more than once. That gets somewhat complicated, but you said its out of scope so I couldn't be bothered and just chopped the buffer after a match :P